# Java Generics insertion on wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Java is not allowing me to add a subclass of the Type declaration in this class

```
public class Exam<T> {

    public  void set(Holder<? super T> hold){

    }
    public  T get(Holder<? extends T> holder){ return holder.get();}


    public static void main (String[] args){
        Exam<Question> eq = new Exam<Question>();
        eq.set(new Holder<Identification>());
    }
}
```

Where Identification is a subclass of Question.

and this how my holder class looks like

```
public class Holder<T> {
    T item;

    public void set(T item){ this.item = item; }
    public T get(){return item;}
}
```

**ERROR**

```
The method set(Holder<? super Question>) in the type Exam<Question> is not applicable for the arguments (Holder<Identification>)
```

Comment: `Identification` is a subclass of `Question`, while you declare in `set` that it should be a superclass.

Comment: Identification is a subclass of Question, not a superclass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error looks pretty self-explanatory to me - the `set` method expects a `Holder<? super Question>` and you're trying to give it a Holder of something that is a subclass of `Question`.  As written, `Exam.set` could take a `Holder<Object>`, for example, but not a `Holder<Identification>`.

A good way to think about `extends` and `super` in generics is in terms of assignment: `T extends Foo` will accept any type `T` that you could use on the right hand side of an assignment to `Foo` without casting, i.e.

```
Foo something = new T();
```

(treat this as pseudocode - I know you're not really allowed to `new` a type varaible).  Conversely, `T super Foo` accepts any T you could use on the left hand side of an assignment without casting:

```
T myThing = new Foo();
```

In your specific example, `Identification i = new Question()` isn't legal without a cast, so a `Holder<? super Question>` parameter can't accept a `Holder<Identification>` value.

Comment: I was expecting to see that it would accept anything as long as it extends T or in this anything that extends Question

Comment: why is it not allowed to have Holder<Identification> isn't Identification a subclass of Question?

Comment: I've added a bit of clarification about how I think about `extends` and `super` when I'm trying to work out which to use where.

Answer (score 1):

`Exam<T>` expects a `Holder<T>` that can hold **any subclass of T**. That's what the `super` does. You are passing a `Holder<Identification>` but `Identification` is neither `T` nor a superclass of it.

Comment: then what is it difference from ? extends T?

Comment: @user962206 `Holder<? extends T>` means that the method expects **any holder** that can hold a subclass of T. You could pass the `Holder<Identification>` then but you couldn't use `Holder.set(T)` because `T` is unknown in this context. However, `Holder.get()` works because the `T` it returns **must** be a subclass of `Exam`'s `T`.

Answer (score 1):

change set method of class Enum to

```
public  void set(Holder<? extends T> hold){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic is invariant. That could be an answer for you. Invariant means that Type2 is a subclass of Type1 so it doesn't mean that List is a List.

Answer (score 0):

It works (but has a different meaning, of course) if you write

```
public  void set(Holder<? extends T> hold){ }
```